# Deserializing my JSON into POCO not populating few fields

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have below json which I need to deserialize in `C#` -

```
{
   "clientSettings":[
      {
         "clientId":12345,
         "entries":[
            {
               "key":"abc",
               "value":false
            },
            {
               "key":"def",
               "value":false
            },
            {
               "key":"ghi",
               "value":false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "clientId":9876,
         "entries":[
            {
               "key":"lkmn",
               "value":false
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "productSettings":[
      {
         "productId":11,
         "entries":[
            {
               "key":"jkl",
               "value":true
            },
            {
               "key":"mno",
               "value":true
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "productId":12,
         "entries":[
            {
               "key":"jkl",
               "value":true
            },
            {
               "key":"mno",
               "value":true
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "customerSettings":[
      {
         "key":"enableData",
         "value":false
      },
      {
         "key":"minPriceValue",
         "value":"10.28"
      },
      {
         "key":"presentData",
         "value":"AEGIS"
      }
   ],
   "thothTest":{
      "9876":[
         "K"
      ],
      "5431":[
         "A",
         "L"
      ],
      "5123":[
         "L"
      ]
   },
   "osirisTest":{
      "7678":[
         "K"
      ]
   }
}
```

Below is the classes I created to deserialzie json into -

```
public class ProcessHolder : Holder
{
    public IDictionary<int, ISet<string>> OsirisTest { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<int, ISet<string>> ThothTest { get; set; }
}

public class Holder
{
    public IList<Mapping> CustomerSettings { get; set; }
    public IList<ClientSettingsMapping> ClientSettings { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductSettingsMapping> ProductSettings { get; set; }
}

public class Mapping
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSettingsMapping : Mapping
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}

public class ClientSettingsMapping : Mapping
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

- I want to load all `customerSettings` values into `CustomerSettings` object of `Holder` class.
- Similarly I want to load all `clientSettings` values into `ClientSettings` object of `Holder` class.
- Similarly all `productSettings` values into `ProductSettings` object of `Holder` class.
- Similarly `thothTest` values into `ThothTest` and `osirisTest` values into `OsirisTest` object.

I was trying with below code but somehow I am not able to see `Key` and `Value` variables being populated inside `Mapping` class object after deserializing my above json.

```
private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var jsonContent = File.ReadAllText("/beta/Downloads/test.json");
    var config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProcessHolder>(jsonContent, serializerSettings);
    if (config == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Some Parsing Issue");
    }
    // using config object here
}
```

What is wrong I am doing here? I just need to deserialize my json into above classes and give me `ProcessHolder` object back which I can use later on.

Comment: Just as a note: You are currently relying on your JSON converter assuming that the camel case names in your JSON and the pascal case names in your code are the same (e.g "clientId" == "ClientId"). Instead you should look into using the [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) to specify the name manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your JSON, `clientSettings` and `productSettings` have `entries` array. There is no corresponding matching property in your class definition for same.
I would suggest to modify your class definition as per JSON. Try below and see if it helps:

```
    public class ProductSettingsMapping 
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public IList<Mapping> Entries { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClientSettingsMapping 
    {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public IList<Mapping> Entries { get; set; }
    }
```

**Second** option - if you are not able to modify classes, you can amend JSON. I am providing sample for `clientSettings`

```
{
"clientSettings": [
    {
        "clientId": 12345,
        "key": "abc",
        "value": false
    }, 
    {
        "clientId": 12345,
        "key": "def",
        "value": false
    }, 
    {
        "clientId": 12345,
        "key": "ghi",
        "value": false
    },
    {
        "clientId": 9876,    
        "key": "lkmn",
        "value": false
    }
]
}
```

You can update `productSettings` accordingly.

**Third** option is to parse into `JObject` and then convert to your classes.
A sample for `clientSettings`

```
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = "{'clientSettings':[{'clientId':12345,'entries':[{'key':'abc','value':false},{'key':'def','value':false},{'key':'ghi','value':false}]},{'clientId':9876,'entries':[{'key':'lkmn','value':false}]}],'productSettings':[{'productId':11,'entries':[{'key':'jkl','value':true},{'key':'mno','value':true}]},{'productId':12,'entries':[{'key':'jkl','value':true},{'key':'mno','value':true}]}],'customerSettings':[{'key':'enableData','value':false},{'key':'minPriceValue','value':'10.28'},{'key':'presentData','value':'AEGIS'}],'thothTest':{'9876':['K'],'5431':['A','L'],'5123':['L']},'osirisTest':{'7678':['K']}}";
            var parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
            var parsedClientSettings = parsed["clientSettings"];
            List<ClientSettingsMapping> clientSettings = new List<ClientSettingsMapping>();
            foreach (var parsedClientSetting in parsedClientSettings)
            {
                var clientId = parsedClientSetting.Value<int>("clientId");
                foreach (var entry in parsedClientSetting["entries"])
                {
                    clientSettings.Add(new ClientSettingsMapping { ClientId = clientId, Key = entry["key"].ToString(), Value = entry["value"].ToString() });
                }
            }
            ProcessHolder processHolder = new ProcessHolder() { ClientSettings = clientSettings };
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: I see. I think it makes sense now. Also is there any way I can keep my old classes as it is  and still deserialize everything into it? Or maybe if I cannot deserialize my json into my classes but can we convert them into the same structure by using some new classes maybe? I want to load json into my old classes exactly as the way they are as of now. Reasoning behind this is it's a legacy system so I cannot modify these classes and these classes are being used at lot of places. We recently redesigned the json to follow this new format.

Comment: I have updated my answer on how you can modify JSON to fit class definition

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. The json you just posted in your answer, my json was like that exactly (and it worked with my POCO) since starting but I have to redesign my json for some reason and thats why I came up with this new json design as mentioned in my question. Now I don't want to change my POCOs which I already have (since it is being used in multiple places like 60+ classes references) and I wanted to see if I can make my new json work with old POCOs classes.

Comment: .. I mean I know we cannot directly deserialize my new JSON to my POCO classes but can we do something in between to convert new JSON into my POCO classes? Like converting it to some new classes and then map that to old POCO class if possible?

Comment: In that case you can parse and load into `JArray` and `JObject` classes provided by Json.Net. Once you have that ready, you can convert to your classes. Involves slightly more work but is doable. [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonObject.htm) , [JArray](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonArray.htm)

Comment: yeah I think thats what I am looking for exactly. Do you think you can provide an example for that which can work with my JSON and POCO in my question?

Comment: Added a sample for `clientSettings`. You can follow same pattern for others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222550/discussion-between-david-todd-and-gkulshrestha).

Answer (score 1):

You should define "entries" in both ProductSettingsMapping and ClientSettingsMapping class.

```
public class ProductSettingsMapping 
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public IList<Mapping> entries { get; set; }
}
public class ClientSettingsMapping 
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public IList<Mapping> entries { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I see. I think it makes sense now. Also is there any way I can keep my old classes as it is  and still deserialize everything into it? Or maybe if I cannot deserialize my json into my classes but can we convert them into the same structure by using some new classes maybe? I want to load json into my old classes exactly as the way they are as of now. Reasoning behind this is it's a legacy system so I cannot modify these classes and these classes are being used at lot of places. We recently redesigned the json to follow this new format.